# Template does not exist error when template exists

Tags: python, django

Getting the error message template does not exist even though the template is in the referenced folder

Here is part of the structure of my project

```
classroom
-->templates
---->classroom
------>teachers
       app-instructor-profile.html
       app-instructor-dashboard.html
```

This is what I have on urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('teachers/', include(([
        path('', teachers.QuizListView.as_view(), name='app-instructor-dashboard'),
        path('logout', teachers.logout_request, name="logout"),
        path('edit_user', teachers.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='teachers')),
```

home.html (app-instructor-dashboard)

```
<li><a href={% url 'teachers:edit_user' %}>Edit Profile</a></li>
```

teachers.py (views.py)

```
def edit_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')
    else:
        form =UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'teachers:app-instructor-profile', args)
```

However, when I click the link which should redirect me to the edit-profile view I get the error message:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /teachers/edit_user
>   teachers:app-instructor-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-profile.html', args)
```

in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
  .....
```

hope it helps

Comment: @Emm see the update just remove first / from template path